# Why AWS VPC is named as VPC (Virtual Private Cloud) ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc

What i understand from Cloud is , it is something to share computing resources (RAM,CPU,Network etc) among several virtual instances on that cloud infrastructure. [read here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing)

But in case of AWS VPC , it have nothing to do with RAM,CPU etc, It is just something Like VPN, where we create our private network.

So why it is named as Virtual Private Cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its mostly a networking and security model. Classic, which existed before VPC, had very limited control of network and security. VPC allows you control of subnets, network interfaces, inbound and outbound security rules.

Comment: Yeah true , then why they named it as cloud ?

Comment: Its still on an abstracted infrastructure. You don't get direct control of any hardware. All your instances are virtual machines.